# How to make a field read-only if I enter some data on another field?

Tags: angularjs

This is an example on W3Schools, but how should I proceed with a text field ?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="all">
<br>
<input type="text" ng-readonly="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

checking if model value of the other field is not empty then enable read-only.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.first = "";
   $scope.second = "";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooController">
     <p>First Name:
        <input ng-model="first"/>
     </p>
     <p>Last Name:
        <input ng-model="second" ng-readonly="first !== ''"/>
     </p>
  </div>  
</body>
```